# Is there a way to have an ngMaxlength attribute present on an input element but have it have a value of "Infinity"?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is there a way to have an ngMaxlength attribute present on an input element but have it have a value of "Infinity" (yes I know I could do this by not having the attribute altogether, but that would require a refactor which I'm trying to avoid)?

I've tried setting the ngMaxlength to `0`, `-1`, `infinity` and `Infinity` and none of them seem to work.

We're on [**AngularJS 1.0.5**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.5/docs/api/ng.directive:input.text) by the way.

---

Per a comment, here's what I'm trying to do:

We have a directive that lets our programmers write CRUD-y tables in the following way (this example doesn't show delete and several other features that are irrelevant to my question, in case you were wondering why I say CRUD and not CRU):

```
<crud-table url="api/url-to-perform-get-post-and-put-on">
   <crud-table-column title="Title of Column 0" field="fieldThatContainsData0" type="text"></row>
   <crud-table-column title="Title of Column 1" field="fieldThatContainsData1" type="checkbox"></row>
<crud-table>
```

I'd like to just change the API make `maxlength` an attribute on `<row />` because one of the usages has that requirement.  The easiest way to do this with minimal change to existing code is to just interpolate that value to a `maxlength` attribute above to the `input` element that is created (not show) by the directive when the `type` of the row is `text`.  It's just less work if I can have a value that means "Infinity" I can put inside the `maxlength` attribute instead of having to omit the attribute altogether to convey the same meaning.  If the answer to my question is "You can't" I can figure it out; I just didn't want to refactor the `crud-table-column` directive to not use a template.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MattWay Trying to make the least invasive change possible to satisfy an additional requirement.  I'll edit the question.

Comment: @MattWay I added an explanation.  Let me know if you need more clarification.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Oof Angular 1.0.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [directive implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2544), it parses the value specified if `ng-maxlength` attribute using angular's `int()` function:

```
var maxlength = 0;
attr.$observe('maxlength', function(value) {
    maxlength = int(value) || 0;
    ctrl.$validate();
});
```

which is based on [`parseInt()`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/14183833f9106a3ab4c7621bcf964fc2b5cc96e6/src/Angular.js#L355):

```
function int(str) {
    return parseInt(str, 10);
}
```

And I don't see the easy way for `parseInt()` to return `infinity` while trying to parse a string into int.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @WordsLikeJared note that I'm very far from angular expert, I've just read the source code and made conclusions of it. I've used master branch, so the situation for 1.0.5 can be different. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, you just set the value to `-1` or a non-numeric value
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input